# What is the optimised way to search a text and string from multiple tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, full-text-search

I want to search against 2 columns which are in two different tables one is `name` and the other is `description`, of type `string` and `text` respectively.

When I came across various blogs / stuff on the internet, I really get confused to find the fastest way to get data.

There are 100K+ rows in each table.

What I have done so far: I created a `tsvector` column for table containing description  and indexed it with `GIN`. But I am confused on how to do that for the name column?

I can't use `ilike '%{keyword}%'` as it doesn't use indexing.

Is it good to use full text search for `name` (string type) also, or what will be the best way for my case?

Thanks in advance

```
select *
from 
    ((select name as "customId", id as aid 
      from accounts 
      where name ilike '%cust%' limit 10)

     union all

     (select t2."customId", null 
      from t2 
      where t2.tsv @@ to_tsquery('cust') limit 10)
) e2
```

Comment: You have found the best way.

Comment: Hi thnks for the reply, u mean using fts for name column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to search using `UNION ALL` is good.

To speed up the substring search, you can use a trigram index:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON accounts USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

Comment: so can i able to search with ilike '%{keyword}%' after this?

Comment: yeah.. got it from the kryword "trgm". if any one want know more https://scoutapm.com/blog/how-to-make-text-searches-in-postgresql-faster-with-trigram-similarity  ThankYou Laurenz